# Code::Blocks/ Dev-c++: error: iostream: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I downloaded Code::Blocks from here: http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26

I'm learning c programming. When I run the following program, I get error:

```
iostream: No such file or directory
error: syntax error before "namespace"
warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `std'
warning: data definition has no type or storage class
In function `main':
error: `cout' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
error: for each function it appears in.)
error: `cin' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I'm running the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x;

  x = 0;
  do {
    // "Hello, world!" is printed at least one time
    //  even though the condition is false
    cout<<"Hello, world!\n";
  } while ( x != 0 );
  cin.get();
}
```

I tried Dev-C++, I get the same error.
How to fix this?

Comment: If you want to learn C, change learning material fast because that's C++

Comment: Well, the code you're showing is C++, not C, so I'm guessing you're trying to compile them as C and that's why it fails.

Answer (score 15):

Is this in a file like "program.c" or "program.cpp"?  If it's a .c file, then your compiler may be interpreting it as C, and not C++.  This could easily cause such an error.  It's possible to "force" the compiler to treat either such extension as the other, but by default, .c files are for C, and .cpp files are compiled as C++.

It's either this, or somehow your default "include" directories for the standard library are not set up right, but I don't know how you'd fix that, as that'd be compiler/environment dependent.

Answer (score 7):

I also had that problem when trying to run my first program in Code::Blocks. My file was saved with '.c' extension as 'test.c' and when I saved it as 'test.cpp', it worked fine.

It is also worth mentioning that I had to **restart Code::Blocks before new 'test.cpp' file was compiled successfully**.

Answer (score 2):

While saving your source code before compiling just save the name with extension ".cpp". You wont get the error..

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

Change #include < iostream.h > 
to #incude < iostream >

Consequently, in your program, change every keyword related to iostream, such as cin cout and endl to std::cout, std::cin and std::endl

That'll do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Use `<iostream>` instead of `<iostream.h>`
and add `std::` before `cout`, `cin` etc

Use           `std::cout << "Welcome";`
instead of    `cout << "Welcome";`

Save the file with `.cpp` extension

Answer (score 0):

you have missing iostream.h file in you mingw directory folder placed inside codeblocks/devc++. what you have to do is just download the file from link given below and replace with your previous mingw folder in codeblocks/devc++.

http://www.4shared.com/rar/owp-D0Km/mingw.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was cause by having a previous version of cgg and cpp in a Perl installation. The Perl structure did not have the correct library files. When I added `C:\MinGW\bin` and `C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin` to the path, I added them at the end so it picked up the Perl install first. I moved the path variable entries to the beginning and reopened my cmd window and it now works because it finds the MinGW version first.

Type path to see your path environment varialble. Mine now looks like:

```
C:\MinGW>path
PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\BluetoothSoftware\;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want to create a c++ file.  But you allowed your computer to auto provide the file extension C/C++.  When it does that it automatically provides a file extension of ".c".  Which is not corect.  You want ".cpp".

Solution: Rename your file with a ".cpp" extension, or else explicitly state your extension when saving new files by putting ".cpp" (without quotes of course) after your intended file name; i.e. specify your file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in Dev-C++ . Instead of iostream.h use iostream also write the using namespace std;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
   cout<<"Hello World\n";
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you written your program in C++ code use c code then your program run correctly

in first line use it

```
#include <Io stream.h>
main ()
{
```

in ending line use it

```
system (pause");
```

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to make a C game right? If you are your code is C++ not C. So if you are trying to make a C game than you should change your code. This *might* help.

Answer (score -2):

Just put "Using namespace std;" before main() to define the scope of identifiers you are using. This will handle your problem easily.

Comment: That's already in the question code. With the proper case, even.

Answer (score -4):

Try including `iostream.h` instead of `iostream`.

Comment: No, don't do that. `iostream.h` is way old. `<iostream>` is what you should include for C++ code.