# Orwell Dev-C++ Fatal Error: "iostream: no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, windows-8.1, iostream, dev-c++

I am attempting to compile a header file in Orwell Dev-C++ that was written on another machine. I've just downloaded Dev-C++ so I'm not very familiar with it. Below is a snippet of my code that is causing a problem:

```
#ifndef JOB_H
#define JOB_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

From this, I get the following compile-time error:

```
[Error] iostream: No such file or directory
```

But when I comment out the `#include <iostream>` line I get the same error.

After getting this message I wrote a quick "Hello World" program and ran it with no problem, so I'm confused as to what could be causing the above error message and how I could solve it.

Comment: What are the differences between your hello world (that works) and this (that doesn't)?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270780/codeblocks-dev-c-error-iostream-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1

Comment: @Cameron the only difference are my hello world is saved to my desktop and was written on my computer(a windows 8 computer) in devc++ while the file that im trying to compile was written on another computer (a mac) and is apart of a bigger project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem @beed was correct. Dev C++ associates .h extensions as c file headers where as i wanted to compile it as a c++ header. The only solution i have is to change the extensions to .hpp unless i can change the file association in devC++